# SEM model comparison

Tags: model, aic, structural-equation-modeling, model-comparison, bic

I have problem choosing a better measurement model between two (i.e., A and B). Both models have acceptable fit indices. For example, the RMSEA of A is .056; the RMSEA of B is .067. By RMSEA, A seems to be more better fitted. The cutoff value set in my thesis was .08.
The AIC and BIC value of model A is 146.88; 266.61. And the AIC and BIC of model B is 136.41; 249.65. By AIC and BIC, model B seems to be better fitted because they are smaller.
Should I choose the model A because it has smaller RMSEA or should I choose the model B because it has smaller AIC and BIC values?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

AIC/BIC take parsimony into account. RMSEA doesn't.

You don't tell us about the chi-square and df (which would help) but in this situation I'd use AIC/BIC.